# Creating multiple reports using a master file with data from multiple files

Tags: excel, vba

I have created a master excel report with 5 main tabs, 3 of which contain multiple pivots that draw their data from 3 separate CSV files. The CSV files do not have a single common denominator and cannot be joined. I need to replicate the master ~500 times for different users. Each user can only see their own info. Any suggestions?

What I have thought of so far is add 4 extra tabs to the main file - 3 containing data for each of the pivot tabs and one I use as control room - due to the number of files I'm breaking them down into smaller groups and using the names from a range with variable size.
I am currently trying to write a code that will:

1. save individual copies of the master file
2. filter the CSVs only copy one individual user at a time data into the respective data tab of the respective user report
3. refresh the pivots
4. delete the extra tabs

So far I have only managed to do step 1.

```
Sub SaveUserReports()
  Dim wb As Workbook
  Dim rNames As Range, c As Range, r As Range

  'Current file's list of names and ids on sheet1.
  Set rNames = Worksheets("Control_Room").Range("K8", Worksheets("Control_Room").Range("K8").End(xlDown))
  'Path and name to master workbook to open for copy, saveas.
  Set wb = Workbooks.Open(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\TestCopy2.xlsx")

  For Each c In rNames
    With wb
      .Worksheets("Control_Room").Range("k8").Value = c
      'Path and name for copied workbook
      .SaveAs filename:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "\UserReports\" & c.Value & ".xlsx", _
        FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False
    End With
    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
  Next c
  wb.Close
End Sub
```

Could you please help me either with steps 2-4 or suggest any alternatives? I'm open to any working automated solution.

For steps 2-4, I have (only with 1 of the CSV, as I can replicate it once I get it to work):

```
Sub Import_Data()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim GBR_Code As Range
    Dim row As Long
    Dim col As Long
    Dim ImportString As String
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim destwb As Workbook
    Dim rNames As Range, c As Range
    Dim iCol As Long
    Dim lo As Range


    Set rNames = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Control_Room").Range("K8:K9")
    Set destwb = Workbooks.Open(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & "November GBR.xlsx")
    Set lo = destwb.Sheets("GBR_Data").UsedRange
    iCol = 1

      For Each c In rNames
        Set wb = Workbooks.Open(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\UserReports\" & c.Value & ".xlsx")
        wb.Worksheets("Control_Room").Range("k8").Value = c
        Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
        destwb.Sheets("GBR_Data").UsedRange.AutoFilter Field:=iCol, Criteria1:=c

        wb.Worksheets("GBR_Data").UsedRange.Clear

          'Copy GBR data from data workbook into report workbook
        destwb.Worksheets("GBR_Data").Range("A2:V100000").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy wb.Sheets("GBR_Data").Range("A2")



NewWkb.Sheets("Overview").PivotTables("PivotTable1").RefreshTable

NewWkb.Sheets("Overview").PivotTables("PivotTable2").RefreshTable

NewWkb.Sheets("Overview").PivotTables("PivotTable3").RefreshTable

NewWkb.Sheets("Overview").PivotTables("PivotTable4").RefreshTable

NewWkb.Sheets("Overview").PivotTables("PivotTable5").RefreshTable

NewWkb.Sheets("Overview").PivotTables("PivotTable6").RefreshTable


          'Application.DisplayAlerts = False
          'NewWkb.Sheets("GBR_Data").Delete
          'Application.DisplayAlerts = True


          wb.Close SaveChanges = True

      Next c


End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. please see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and don't forget to read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question). Also check out the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and more good information at ["help center".](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: In addition to the above, this is on here lots of times.  Please show your starting point, if the starting point is 0 lines of code, then you need to have a go first

Comment: Hi Nathan_Sav, 
I am fairly new to VBA but I do manage to get by, mostly with content from these threads. I've added to my question the code I have so far.

Comment: I guess `NewWkb` should be `destwb`. So what is going wrong in the code you posted?

Comment: @omegastripes sorry, I had ' the NewWkb bit as I was testing the rest but it should be wb - destwb is the csv I'm copying the data from. The problem with this code is that the only thing it does is filter the csv but it doesn't copy paste the data. It doesn't give me any error messages either, it just doesn't do much. Any idea why that might be?

Comment: Replace `wb.Close SaveChanges = True` with `wb.Close SaveChanges:=True`. And one more note, just to avoid mess,.. source (src) is where you copy from, destionation (dest) is where you copy to.

Comment: @omegastripes Oh wow!! I can't believe that this was the only thing wrong - it works perfectly now and I was able to replicate it for all 3 sources!! I've also followed your advise and changed source and destination. Thank you so much for your help!